# Connecting Azure PaaS website with a SQL DB Iaas VM. How do I get them on the same machine

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

I can't get the database for a web app converted so I wanted to have the front end/Web API in the cloud and the DB on a SQL server box in the office.

Then I realized I better put the SQL Server on a VM and somehow get it physically close to wherever the web site on the cloud is. How do I do this ? Am I going about this the right way ?

The closer they are together the better bandwidth I would assume

Comment: What can't you use Azure SQL? If there is good reason then your proposal seems ok. Just make sure the Website and SQL VM are in the same data center.

Comment: im sorry.. I forgot to mention we tried that and too many issues with the database

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option would be to use Azure SQL instead of spinning up an IaaS instance.  When you create an Azure Website you have the option of creating a SQL database at the same time, and everything just works out of the box.  [Here's](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/) a relevant tutorial.

If you use an IaaS SQL instance then you would need to add an MSSQL endpoint to your VM to make it publicly accessible, and then connect to it from your app using the VM Cloud Service domain name (yourservice.cloudapps.net).  (Thanks to Rick Rainey for pointing out this option.)

Also, as Rick pointed out, you would want to add an ACL on the MSSQL endpoint and lock it down so only your app's virtual IP (VIP) can access it.

The downside of the IaaS route is that there's more administration work maintaining the SQL Server instance and VM, but it's definitely feasible.

A third option, if you don't want your SQL VM accessible to the internet, is to host your app in a Cloud Service, create a Virtual Network, and put the Cloud Service and SQL VM on the virtual network so they can talk to each other.  (Azure Websites cannot be on a virtual network which is why you'd have to use a cloud service.)

Comment: It is not a requirement to create a Virtual Network if you go the route of hosting SQL Server on an Azure Virtual Machine.  Your Cloud Service (website) can still connect to your Cloud Service (SQL VM) using the DNS name to address the SQL VM.  So, if your SQL Server is running in mysqlvmsvc.cloudapp.net, then that is what you would use for your "Data Source" in your connection string.  To do this, you will need to add the "MSSQL" endpoint to the SQL VM.  I would strongly suggest adding an ACL to that endpoint too so that only the Cloud Service (website) VIP can access it.

Comment: You're correct, the virtual network would only be required if you didn't want to expose your database to the internet.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hey Ben, I would recommend adding the ACL statement (see earlier comment) to your updated answer because with the ACL you don't make the SQL VM publicly accessible.

Comment: Forgot to mention we tried to use SQL azure already but too many issues with the database so putting setting up a VM seems like the next logical step..

Comment: How do I ensure that the VM and the cloud app are as close to each other as possible? Is it by putting them in the same RESOURCE GROUP or is it by putting them in the same location? or do I need to do something more complex?